# Saving TIFF as PNG

Tags: c#, tiff, image-conversion

I have such code

```
using (Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sourceStream))
{
    Guid objGuid = image.FrameDimensionsList[0];
    FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);
    int pageCount = image.GetFrameCount(objDimension);

    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
    {
          image.SelectActiveFrame(objDimension, i);
          resultStream = new MemoryStream();
          image.Save(resultStream, ToSystemImageFormat(outputFormat));
          result.Add(resultStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

the purpose - to save each TIFF's page as png and store it as byte's array. The problem that on my two WIN7 computers that I tested it works fine. But I have one WinXP computer and this piece of code fails with "Parameter not valid" exception. The TIFF document always the same. Somebody knows where is the problem?

I tried to use ImageConverter:

```
ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
using (Image image = (Image)imageConverter.ConvertFrom(sourceContent))
{
     Guid objGuid = image.FrameDimensionsList[0];
     FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);
     int pageCount = image.GetFrameCount(objDimension);

     for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
     {
            image.SelectActiveFrame(objDimension, i);
            resultStream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(resultStream, ToSystemImageFormat(outputFormat));
            result.Add(resultStream.ToArray());
      }
}
```

but it fails too with same exception.
Thank you

UPD#1: It fails on Image.FromStream() method. I forgot to mention that the most TIFF documents are converted without any problem, it fails on specific ones. But on WIN7 verything fine even with these specific ones.

Comment: What line of code causes the exception?

Comment: Please post the entire exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Cant post full stack trace because WinXP it is not developer computer

Comment: Can you modify the application to log the full exception Message and StackTrace?  Also, what is in sourceStream at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that winxp has limited support for png. You can't load icon files that are actually compressed pngs (the standard on win 7) in .net 4.0 running on winxp, you get the same exception.

Comment: The problem that it fails on specific TIFF document, the most of them are converted without any problem

Comment: Oh I see, your wording threw me off. You always get a parameter exception when trying to run your code on this particular TIFF? Could you post the stack trace? Sounds like that particular TIFF either is corrupt, structured in such a way that the image libs don't understand, or use some feature of TIFF that the image libs don't have implemented. As I understand it, TIFF is a pretty complicated standard.

Comment: The main problem that TIFF that fails on WinXP - works on Win7

Comment: I understand that, and my answer is still consistent with that behavior. .Net ultimate uses the facilities of the OS to handle images. Win 7 probably has a more complete implementation of TIFF. This particular image uses some feature of TIFF that the implementation on Win XP doesn't support, but Win 7 does.

Comment: That I understand too. The problem is how to fix it

Comment: I know this is a lot of work, but to figure this out, I suppose I'd recommend tearing apart the TIFF with debugging tools to find out what the structure of it is and what the feature usage is. Then do that with your other images, and compare. I'm guessing that this TIFF uses some feature that the other ones don't. Alternatively, dig around for a TIFF library you can use with .Net that has more complete support and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/). Alternately, you could go with libtiff (C++ code), but I suspect LibTiff.Net will be easier to call from your .Net code.